# the double circumflex operator in scala

Tags: scala

I'm searching for a long time now, but I probably didn't find the right place.

So here I am: What does the ^^ operator do in Scala?

Comment: See: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/09/scala-parser-combinators.html

Comment: In scala there are no operators, only methods and they could mean anything depending on which object they are called. So if you want a definitive answer, you have to provide some code.

Comment: Or, in other words, every single-argument method is an infix operator.

Comment: You can find all "operators" (really, those are simple methods as mentioned by drexin) in the standard library here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#index.index-_

Comment: use SO search [to see examples of usage:](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[scala]+%22^^%22)

Comment: I was [ranting about this operator](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/379600827930787840) just the other day. Short answer: it's a confusing alias for `map` on parsers.

Comment: @mikołak That's not quite true anymore in Scala 3. As of Scala 3, only methods with symbol names or methods explicitly marked `infix` are able to be used with the infix operator syntax.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: true, but a) the comment was made almost 10 years ago and b) it still applies to Scala 2.x.

Comment: @mikołak Hahaha, my mistake! Someone edited the question, so I saw it in recent and didn't notice the age. I'd best pay attention next time :)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: np, happens :).