# What does $$[T] mean in method name

Tags: scala, generics, naming-conventions

I recently came across a odd syntax in Scala that I've never seen before and there seems to be no mention of it anywhere in Scala docs. I have a suspicion that this is just an odd way to name a method, but wanted to check if it's not something else.

```
class Reader(props: PropertyResolver, prefix: Option[String] = None {
   def $$[T](name: String)(implicit conv: String => T): T => props.$[T](prefix.fold(name)(_ + name))
}
```

Just a general wondering whether I understand correctly that somebody was crazy enough to call method $$

Comment: Yes that is juts a method name, and yes someone was just crazy enough to do that, and yes this is the kind of stuff why we good **Scala** devs get criticized on the internet because of a moron with too much free time.

Comment: Thank you, please post as a response so I can upvote you :)

Comment: Maybe [methods in scala can be named with any name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76138507/7214091) can help you to understand a bit more about it

Comment: Nothing crazy, the more `$` you put in a name, the more money is going to make you. :P

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that the incredible individual that came up with this pinnacle of programing commited with message "Dolla dolla bills"

Answer (score 2):

### Why it works

Despite [violating naming conventions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers), `$$` is a valid method identifier. It's ordinary even by JVM's standards, i.e. it does not require any Scala-specific name mangling (the dollar sign `$` is a valid identifier name in Java). This is all valid Java ([bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057101/2707792), but valid):

```
// Compiles just fine when saved in `$.java`.
class $ {

  private String _$;

  public $(String __) {
    _$ = __;
  }

  private void _$_() {
    System.out.println(_$);
  }

  private static void $$($ ___) {
    ___._$_();
  }

  public static void main(String... ____) {
    $$(new $("Dude, why..."));
  }
}
```

It's in no way specific to the JVM either. JavaScript's jQuery has been doing this for decades. This is valid JS code:

```
function $(selector) { return { click(){} } }
```

and allows you to do these typical jQuery-style-selections, as in

```js
$('#header').click((ev) => {
  /* ... */
})
```

### Why you shouldn't do it

While the JVM doesn't care and works with `$`s in identifiers just fine, in the *actual programming languages* (Scala, Java), the usage of `$` in identifiers is strongly discouraged, because your identifiers might inadvertently collide with synthetic identifiers generated by the compilers. For example, this Java program:

```java
// javac Dollarz.java
class Dollarz {
  static class A {}
}

class Dollarz$A {}
```

does not actually compile, because our manually defined `Dollarz$A` class collides with the synthetic name that the `javac` generates for the nested class `A`.

Similarly, for Scala, the following code snippet:

```
// Try `scalac Dollarz.scala`
class Dollarz$
object Dollarz
```

produces a strange error message `Dollarz is already defined as class Dollarz in Dollarz.scala`, despite `class Dollarz$` and `object Dollarz` compiling just fine on their own. The problem this time is that `scalac` tries to generate a synthetic class `Dollarz$` for the companion object `Dollarz`, which then ends up colliding with the already defined class `Dollarz$`.

Moreover: even if your code with `$`-characters in identifiers compiles *now*, the backward compatibility is not guaranteed, i.e. you should treat all names with `$`s as reserved by the compiler designers. If in Scala 3.45 someone decides to generate bunch of synthetic methods `$$`, `$$1`, `$$2` ... on every class, and your code breaks because of the collisions, then it will be *your* fault. The [Spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers) explicitly tells you not to use it in user programs:

> The ‘$’ character is reserved for compiler-synthesized identifiers. User programs should not define identifiers that contain ‘$’ characters.

Comment: "It's ordinary even by JVM's standards" — disagree, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056918/when-should-i-use-the-dollar-symbol-in-a-variable-name

Comment: @SethTisue I've updated my answer, added a paragraph on the naming conventions, and why bad things can happen if one actually uses it in user-written code. Still, I'm pretty sure that the JVM simply doesn't care: it's all about naming conventions in the languages built on top of the JVM, the JVM itself sees no differences between `a`, `b`, ... `z` and `$`.